# Idiom/slang for the expression "to use in an unwitting fashion/manner"

Tags: slang, idiom-request

In the following video (2.12), the commentator is using the expression "to use in an unwitting fashion", whose meaning is perfectly understandable. My question is about how the same idea might be expressed in professional slang.  I mean in casual conversations between those who might sometimes professionally deal, one way or another, with the situations where this kind of treating certain persons is barely avoidable.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ojjCErW2NLU

The only one that comes to my mind is "to use one as a pawn", but I'm not sure whether it suggests the "pawn's" total unawareness of the advantage which those who are using them may gain.

!BTW, for the expression used in the video, [Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+an+unwitting+fashion%2Cin+an+unwitting+manner&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=17&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20an%20unwitting%20manner%3B%2Cc0) shows no results, whereas for "in an unwitting *manner*" it gives quite a few links.

Comment: fashion and manner are synonymous. Try looking at: ludwig.guru, a press search engine for texts. What makes you think there is slang for this?

Comment: @Lambie - Re: What makes you think there is slang for this? I just have a gut feeling based on something I think I once chanced upon in a book - it might've been one by Don Winslow or the like read, I'm not sure. How come that I started searching for the expression - it might be a phrasal-prepositional verb, though - is another question. Searching by the definition "to use in an unwitting manner/fashion" has been of no avail, so I'm still at it...

Comment: It is not easy to find synonyms for phrases. I just meant for you to see that fashion and manner are the same here.

Comment: @Lambie - Re: fashion and manner are the same here. Oh, that... I just meant the frequency - thanks, though:)

Comment: There are just tons of slang words: dupe, fall guy, sucker, pigeon, mug, mark, chump, patsy: all those are unwitting victims of someone's actions.

Comment: @Lambie - Oh, thanks again - I could go on with the list of such nouns - but what I'm looking for is something that stands for the particular action, that is of having one, be them a dupe or a smart.ss, being used in an unwitting manner, that's it and that's that:)